# What does "get a grip" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Because data's harder to **get a grip** on than logos, it can be tough to "shape" your database in a way that gets your message in front of the people it's most suited to. So here's a 12-item checklist of questions to ask yourself based on Marketscan's latest report on campaign data, from which most of the figures cited below are drawn.

What does "get a grip " mean here?
Does it mean that understanding data is harder than understanding logos?

Comment: Learn to use OALD - http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grip_1#grip_1__92

Comment: @Tetsujin I checked this word in the dictionary. It means controlling emotion. but here I think has a different meaning.

Comment: It's interchangeable with 'come to grips' from OALD, though perhaps idiomatic. It was just the umpteenth question today that could have used a dictionary, hence my somewhat terse response ;) OALD - come/get to grips with something...
to begin to understand and deal with something difficult..
'I'm slowly getting to grips with the language.'

Comment: @user123: See tetsujin's link, position 3: develop an understanding.

Comment: I voted to reopen, **mainly** because the OP asked about "get a grip" and the question was **changed** to indicate the OP was asking about "get a grip on." Also, the OP did look the word up in the dictionary link posted by @Tetsujin and saw that the phrase 'get a grip' (the phrase the OP asked about) means 'controlling emotion.' IN addition the OP did ask for help in understanding the term he/she asked about when first posting the question about the meaning of **get a grip**.

Comment: Also, I doubt it's easy for an ELL to naturally extend the meaning of "get a grip" to "get a grip on" without assistance. Also, I looked up *grip* in four dictionaries and found most of then wanting in providing clear understandings. If you look up "get a grip" in ODO [it](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/get-a-grip?q=get+a+grip) talks about self control. If in Collins, it says see "get to grips" et al.

Comment: @user123 The phrase you want is actually **get a grip on** and [Definition 4](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grip) of Collins dictionary has the meaning you thought was correct. It says ***understanding**, control, or mastery of a subject, problem, etc (esp in such phrases as get or have a grip on)*. You guessed the meaning correctly. Good job.

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question because I can barely understand the excerpt myself, which makes it a good ELL question despite the dubious premise.

Comment: Sorry that lots of answerer's here couldn't understand why this was difficult to get. I apologise :D Well done Carsmack!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, that excerpt you cited looks like poorly written marketing drivel — informal and barely making sense. What does *"shape" your database* even mean?

I think that *get a grip* is being used in this context as a synonym for *understand*, as if your brain is metaphorically grabbing a slippery concept.

However, this sample is poor writing, and you shouldn't use it as an example to learn from.

In other contexts, *Get a grip!* is commonly short for *Get a grip on reality*, which is a way to tell a delusional person to come to their senses.

Comment: yes, it was too hard for me too understand this text. I read it many times but, I didn't understand it. It was a first time that I see such a writing.